# OAuth 2.0 - Refresh token only valid after access token used?

Tags: oauth-2.0, token

We're integrating with a system that has the behavior that the refresh token we get is only valid after the access token has been at least used once. Is this a normal behavior? Can add that the behavior was not documented.